# Angular2 Pipe for changing inline style of specific character

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to make an Angular2 pipe that will filter through a line of text and see if a the "#" sybmol is in the text.  If it is, then I would like the color to change to red but only '#' should change to red, not the entire string.  Below is what I have thus far.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'redStar' })
export class RedStarPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(text: string, numLetters: number){
        if(text.includes("*")) {
            if(numLetters === undefined) {
                var str = text.replace('#', '<span style="color: red">*</span>');
                return str;
            }
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: This is the edited code:  transform(text: string){
    if(text.includes("#")){  
            var str = text.replace('#', 'TEST');
            return str;
            }
    else{
        return text;
    }
}

The code is not even replacing the # characters with "TEST"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you want to replace `#` hash character, but in your pipe you are checking the `*` asterisk character.

Just change `if (text.includes("*")) {` to `if (text.includes("#")) {` and it will be working.

Also to allow replacing multiple `#` characters, you need to use regex with `g` modifier:

```
text.replace(/#/g, '<span style="color: red">*</span>')
```

Here is a working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-djvdwb

Comment: Thank you for the response.  When adding the '/#/g' part, the rest of my code is following is messed up.  Is there any syntax I would need to add to format that?

Comment: Well not sure what are you doing wrong, I created a working example for you.

Comment: That helps immensely! Thank you!  I am trying to use this in an ng-template.  Specifically on an expression.
<ng-template let-user>
             {{sampleData | redStar}}
  </ng-template>
I tried to put it in a p tag with the [innerHTML] attribute like you used but got no luck.  do you have any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: You can not use [innerHTML] with ng-template, as ng-template is basically just a placeholder, it will not be present in the resulting HTML markup so you can not fill it with HTML. This looks like its working: `<ng-template [ngIf]="true"><p [innerHTML]="text | redStar"></p></ng-template>`.

Answer (score 1):

here is a fiddle with the soltution https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5am1ni
 pipe.ts

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'
@Pipe({ name: 'redStar' })
export class RedStarPipe implements PipeTransform{
constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
transform(text: string, numLetters: number){
let text1;
if(text.indexOf("#") !== -1){  
    var str = text.replace(/#/g, "<span style='color: red'>*</span>");
    text1 = str;
}else{
   text1 = text;
 }
 return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(text1);;
 }}
```

component.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="name  | redStar"></div>
```